# Objective C: How to extract part of a String (Dates and Phone Numbers)

Tags: objective-c, text, nsstring, extract

I have a string as shown below,

```
NSString * aString = @"This is the 10/32/1993 and Ph: (02) 9423-2323 I want";
```

How can I set the the date and the phone number to two separate stings. "9423-2323" and "10/32/1993"

Comment: Look how to use NSRegularExpression

Answer (score 3):

Use [NSDataDetector](http://nshipster.com/nsdatadetector/):

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber | NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber
                                                           error:&error];

NSString *string = @"This is the 10/32/1993 and Ph: (02) 9423-2323";
[detector enumerateMatchesInString:string
                           options:kNilOptions
                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])
                        usingBlock:
^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
  NSLog(@"Match: %@", result);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe if your string will always contain the same text but different numbers then you can use the following:

```
NSString *stringDate;
NSString *stringPhone;

stringDate  = [aString substringWithRange: NSMakeRange (12, 10)];
stringPhone = [aString substringWithRange: NSMakeRange (38, 9)];
```

You just need to count the correct location of the date (i.e. 12) and the correct location of the phone (i.e. 38)

Comment: but in the text there will be a variation on where the things are how can i do it using a pattern

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [NSScanner](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html#) as shown in [String Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/Scanners.html).

A very rough implementation would be:

```
NSString * aString = @"This is the 10/32/1993 and Ph: (02) 9423-2323 I want";

NSString *phoneString;
NSString *dateString;

NSString *datePrefix = @"This is the ";
NSString *dateSuffix = @"and Ph: (02) ";
NSString *phoneSuffix = @" I want";

NSScanner *scanner= [NSScanner scannerWithString:aString];

[scanner scanString:datePrefix intoString:NULL];
[scanner scanUpToString:dateSuffix intoString:&dateString];
[scanner scanString:dateSuffix intoString:NULL];
[scanner scanUpToString:phoneSuffix intoString:&phoneString];
[scanner scanString:phoneSuffix intoString:NULL];

NSLog(@"\n%@ \n%@", dateString, phoneString);
```